# Modal Button without form validation

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have a modal function that is opened with a `<button>` although when opening the modal it gives a prompt for required form fields.

The required fields don't stop the modal from opening but show over the top and I would like them not to display when opening the modal.

I have attempted using formnovalidate on the button but that then makes the button a submit without validation and I don't want the button to submit the form.

Is there another way to do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
          $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
      
            //Expand or collapse this panel
            $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
      
            //Hide the other panels
            $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
      
          });
        });
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.accordion-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.active, .accordion-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion-content {
    display: none;
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.accordion-content.default {display: block;}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.collapsible {
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <button id="myBtn" style="margin-left: 50px;">Help</button>
    
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>
                <div id="accordion">
                        <p class="accordion-toggle">#AUTOREP</p>
                        <div class="accordion-content default">
      <p></p>
      </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code ([as brief as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), it's hard to even guess what might be happening, let alone suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer was to use an `<input>` with the type set as button, this resolved the issue I was having with the form validation prompt.